# AngularJS custom SortBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-orderby

I have an array with several objects `{id:x , name:y}` retrieved from a Java Enum  and I need to order them alphabetically, but one of the objects must mandatorily be in the bottom of the `<select>` comboBox, how could I achieve this result? I used ng-options with orderBy, but, I can't figure out how to put this particular object into the bottom.

Comment: Have to tried with adding `Particular Object` option at last of `Array`? Show your code it will help other to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to sort in the controller, when you get the data from the server:

1. find the "special" object that should go to the bottom and remove it from the array
2. sort the array, using $filter('orderBy')(array, 'name')
3. push the "special" object to the sorted array
4. expose the sorted array on the scope and use that array in ng-options